# column-count css make the images change when i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

If you could notice when you run the code that the images are changing until it's stop when you refresh the page and i guess this happen because of column-count. Could someone advise. Thanks

This is the page
https://www.mobileimplantlab.ca/galleries

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Conversion')"> Conversion</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Fixed-hybrid')"> Fixed Hybrid</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Removal-bar-over-denture')"> Removable Bar Over Denture</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Surgical-guides')"> Surgical Guides</button>
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
</div><br>
<div class="te">
  <% count = 1 %>
  <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
    <% if g.image1.present? %>
      <ul class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
        <li>
          <div class="cont">
            <%= image_tag g.image1.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{count})" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor",alt: g.title1, title: g.title1%>
          </div>
          <p class="desc" onclick= "openModal();currentSlide(<%= count %>)" ><%=  g.title1 %></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% count = count + 1 %>
    <% end %>
    <% if g.image2.present? %>
      <ul class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
        <li>
          <div class="cont">
            <%= image_tag g.image2.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{count})" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor",alt: g.title2, title: g.title2%>  
          </div>
          <p class="desc" onclick= "openModal();currentSlide(<%= count %>)" ><%= g.title2 %></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% count = count + 1 %>
    <% end %>
    <% if g.image3.present? %>
      <ul class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
        <li>
          <div class="cont">
            <%= image_tag g.image3.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{count})" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor",alt: g.title3, title: g.title3%>
            
          </div>
          <p class="desc" onclick= "openModal();currentSlide(<%= count %>)" ><%= g.title3 %></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% count = count + 1 %>
    <% end %>
    <% if g.image4.present? %>
      <ul class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
        <li>
          <div class="cont">
            <%= image_tag g.image4.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{count})" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor",alt: g.title4, title: g.title4%>
            
          </div>
          <p class="desc" onclick= "openModal();currentSlide(<%= count %>)" ><%= g.title4 %></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% count = count + 1 %>
    <% end %>
    <% if g.image5.present? %>
      <ul class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
        <li>
          <div class="cont">
            <%= image_tag g.image5.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{count})" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor",alt: g.title5, title: g.title5%>
            
          </div>
          <p class="desc" onclick= "openModal();currentSlide(<%= count %>)" ><%= g.title5 %></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% count = count + 1 %>
    <% end %> 
    <% if g.video.present? %>
      <ul class="column <%= g.product_name %>">
        <li>
          <div class="cont">
            <%= video_tag g.video.url, style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{count})",class: "hover-shadow cursor",alt: g.videotitle, title: g.videotitle, autoplay: true, loop: true, controls: false, muted: true,playsinline: true%>
          </div>
          <p class="desc" onclick= "openModal();currentSlide(<%= count %>)" ><%=  g.videotitle %></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% count = count + 1 %>
    <% end %>
      
<% end %>
<!-- END GRID -->
</div>

<!-- END MAIN -->
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
        
          <% if g.image1.present? %>
            <div class="mySlides">
              <%= image_tag g.image1.url, style: "width:100%" ,alt: g.title1,title: g.title1%>
              <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"><%= g.title1 %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <% if g.image2.present? %>
            <div class="mySlides">
              <%= image_tag g.image2.url, style: "width:100%",alt: g.title2,title: g.title2 %>
              <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"><%= g.title2 %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <% if g.image3.present? %>
            <div class="mySlides">
              <%= image_tag g.image3.url, style: "width:100%",alt: g.title3,title: g.title3 %>
              <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"><%= g.title3 %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <% if g.image4.present? %>
            <div class="mySlides">
              <%= image_tag g.image4.url, style: "width:100%",alt: g.title4,title: g.title4 %>
              <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"><%= g.title4 %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <% if g.image5.present? %>
            <div class="mySlides">
              <%= image_tag g.image5.url, style: "width:100%",alt: g.title5,title: g.title5 %>
              <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"><%= g.title5 %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <% if g.video.present? %>
            <div class="mySlides">
              <%= video_tag g.video.url, style: "width:100%", :controls => true ,alt: g.videotitle,title: g.videotitle,playsinline: true %>
              <div class="caption-container">
                <p id="caption"><%= g.videotitle %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>

      <% end %>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
</div>

<style>
.te {
 line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 0px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.te .column {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
.cont{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.cont img,video{
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .te {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .te {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .te {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .te {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.desc{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(57, 57, 57, 0.502);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.column li:hover .desc {
  transform: scale(1);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.column > li {
  flex-basis: 350px; /*width: 350px;*/
  position: relative;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

#caption{
  color: white;
  text-align: center !important;
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .btn {
     padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px !important; */
  }
   .desc{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .close {
      color: white !important;
      position: absolute;
      top: 120px;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 45px;
      font-weight: bold;
      z-index: 1000;
  }
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .desc{
    font-size: 7px;
  }
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
.mySlides img{
  padding-top: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}
 #myBtnContainer{
  display: flex;
}
</style>

<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Whoa! That page is terribly broken! Looks like there is an endless loop in the script somewhere. It will have nothing to do with `column-count`.

Comment: So it's javascript related? Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: By the way, you no longer need to use `-moz-` or `-webkit-` prefixes with `column-count` ... it has been [fully supported on all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=column-count) for years now.

Comment: ok I will remove them